# Change image on icon state change:Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change the "body" background image file on my webpage,when the user toggles between music icon play and pause.

Here is what the CSS for  "body" element looks like :

```
body {
  background: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/665940/intro-bg.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

So in music function, I have two states, play and pause. I tried to change the image in each of the "if" conditions like this :

```
$("#music").click(function() {
  if (playing) {
    // Stop playing
    document.body.style.background = "url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/665940/intro-bg.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed";
    $("body").css({backgroundSize: "cover"});
    audioElement.pause();
  } else {
    // Start playing
    if (!initDone) {
      initDone = true;
       document.body.style.background = "url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/665940/header-background.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed";
      audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
      audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/665940/om_cut.mp3');

      audioElement.addEventListener('ended', function() {
        this.currentTime = 0;
        this.play();
      }, false);
    }

    audioElement.play();
  }

  $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-music fa-stop');
  playing = !playing;
});
```

Now what happens is that when I play the music, the image changes and then when I click the stop icon the image again changes back to my regular image. But then the next time I click play again the image does not change. So it means what I did only gets executed once. How can I make it to happen every time I toggle between the play and pause ?

Comment: Without a real example it's tricky to debug.... But I suggest you toggle a class to the body instead of setting those inline styles.

Comment: @DaniP: Like I said it works , but only gets executed one time. The next time image remains the same even when I toggle the play and pause icons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time through, you are setting this `initDone = true;`

So, on the second and successive calls the `if (!initDone)` condition prevents the image from changing.

Move `document.body.style.background =...` above the condition and it should do what you're looking for.

Comment: Awesome you saved my day. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

in this condition `if (!initDone) { .... }`you just need to make the script which change the background out of it . https://jsfiddle.net/m2s5kho2/

```
var playing = false, initDone = false;
$("#music").click(function() {
  if (playing) {
    // Stop playing
    document.body.style.background = "url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/665940/intro-bg.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed";
    $("body").css({backgroundSize: "cover"});
    audioElement.pause();
  } else {
    // Start playing
       document.body.style.background = "url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/665940/header-background.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed";
    if (!initDone) {
      initDone = true;
      audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
      audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/665940/om_cut.mp3');

      audioElement.addEventListener('ended', function() {
        this.currentTime = 0;
        this.play();
      }, false);
    }
    audioElement.play();
  }

  $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-music fa-stop');
  playing = !playing;
});
```